# jQuery Slider similar to Microsoft one

Tags: jquery, slider, jquery-slider

I am looking for a jquery slider script to look & feel like the one Microsoft has right now on their new website: `http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/default.aspx`

Can someone help me with a link?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean a [carousel](http://google.com/search?q=jquery+carousel). Just be aware that they are not user-friendly and are typically seen as cliché due to their overuse. The first result on that Google search is for "32 best jQuery carousel plugins", just to show you how overused it is.